# Scraping newspaper article titles with google news

Tags: python, web-scraping, google-news

Below is my code for scraping news about domestic violence. This code worked perfectly the first time I used it. But back then I covered only 2-3 months period, I re-tried it with a wider time frame, it returns an empty string. Why might that be and how can I solve it?

```
from GoogleNews import GoogleNews
from newspaper import Article
import pandas as pd

googlenews = GoogleNews(start='24/01/2020', end='23/01/2021')
googlenews.search('Domestic violence')
result = googlenews.result()
df = pd.DataFrame(result)
print(df.head())

for i in range(2,20):
    googlenews.getpage(i)
    result = googlenews.result()
    df = df.append(result)
    df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Shouldn`t you use start date as 23rd of Jan and end date as 24th of Jan?

Comment: One is 2020, the other is 2021:)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. I wrote the dateformat wrong. It should have been 01/24/2020